# Computing spherical harmonic coefficients using Scipy

Tags: python, spherical-harmonics

The `scipy.special.sph_harm` function evaluates a spherical harmonic function at a point. Does Scipy provide any functions to compute the spherical harmonic coefficients for a data set?

Comment: What do you mean by "the spherical harmonic coefficients for a data set"?

Comment: I have some data defined on the surface of a sphere, and I'd like to create a spherical harmonic expansion for this data. I can integrate this data against the harmonic basis functions to get the coefficients, but I'm hoping this is built in to SciPy somehow.

Comment: Just use Spherepack. There's a python wrapper: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspharm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given samples of a function $f(\theta,\phi)$, you will need to numerically evaluate the integral

$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta,\phi)\left[Y_n^{m}(\theta,\phi)\right]^*\sin\theta d\phi d\theta\, ,$$

to obtain the $n,m$th coefficient of your expansion. Hopefully your samples are at some convenient locations on the unit sphere, either uniformly sampled or at Gauss-Legendre nodes.

Comment: You probably want to [Lebedev grid points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebedev_quadrature) instead of Gauss-Legendre nodes.

Comment: Numerical evaluation this integral is poorly conditioned and painful. Which is why people usually just use a software package designed for this specific purpose.